# Passing in parameters with constructor injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, quarkus

I am working on an app where an endpoint is being called to add a user. This calls a service class (that has been injected into the controller class) to add the user. In the service class I have created a custom module that deals with connecting to keycloak and adding users to it. I have that defined as an instance variable in the service class. When I was trying to write unit tests I read that I needed to have it so this module could be defined via construtor or setter methods.
I am now trying to inject the service class via constructor injection with the module as a parameter but not having much luck.

This is my original service class code;

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserService {

   private AuthManager authManager = AuthManagerFactory.getAuthManager(new KeycloakFactoryAuth());

   ...
}
```

But now I am trying;

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserService {

    private AuthManager authManager;

    public UserService(AuthManager authManager) {
        this.authManager = authManager;
    }

   ...
}
```

I am using Quarkus and according to their [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#can-i-use-setter-and-constructor-injection), I don't need a default constructor or define `@Inject` over the constructor. But when I try to run this I get the following error;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.buddydata.AuthManager and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: io.buddydata.service.UserService():authManager
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.buddydata.service.UserService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.buddydata.service.UserService]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1209)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:275)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:134)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:494)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:925)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.buddydata.AuthManager and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: io.buddydata.service.UserService():authManager
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.buddydata.service.UserService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.buddydata.service.UserService]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:411)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:527)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:263)
    ... 13 more


    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:632)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:703)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:302)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.buddydata.AuthManager and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: io.buddydata.service.UserService():authManager
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.buddydata.service.UserService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.buddydata.service.UserService]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1209)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:275)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:134)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:494)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:925)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.buddydata.AuthManager and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: io.buddydata.service.UserService():authManager
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.buddydata.service.UserService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.buddydata.service.UserService]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:411)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:527)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:263)
    ... 13 more

    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:330)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:225)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:609)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:647)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:205)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.buddydata.AuthManager and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: io.buddydata.service.UserService():authManager
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.buddydata.service.UserService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.buddydata.service.UserService]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1209)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:275)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:134)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:494)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:925)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.buddydata.AuthManager and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: io.buddydata.service.UserService():authManager
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.buddydata.service.UserService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.buddydata.service.UserService]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:411)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:527)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:263)
    ... 13 more

    at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:116)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:157)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:328)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.buddydata.AuthManager and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: io.buddydata.service.UserService():authManager
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.buddydata.service.UserService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.buddydata.service.UserService]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1209)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:275)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:134)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:494)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:925)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.buddydata.AuthManager and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: io.buddydata.service.UserService():authManager
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.buddydata.service.UserService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.buddydata.service.UserService]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:411)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:527)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:263)
    ... 13 more
```

I assume/know I need to define that when `AuthManager` is to be injected I should return a new `KeycloakFactoryAuth` object, but where/how do I define this?
Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, this is a very simple case: just create a bean with a producer method that produces the `AuthManager` in application scope, simplest example: `@ApplicationScoped class AuthManagerProducer { private AuthManager authManager = AuthManagerFactory.getAuthManager(new KeycloakFactoryAuth()); @Produces @ApplicationScoped getAuthManager() { return authManager; }}`. You can improve by actually creating the `AuthManager` in a `PostConstruct` method, allow injection of configuration etc.

Comment: That authManager you created manually is not managed by Quarkus, so it does not know to use it. You should create a Bean with this object.

Comment: Cheers @Nikos, worked a treat :+1:

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Nikos Paraskevopoulos a [producer](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html) is what you need but a more elegant solution than field producer coupled with `@PostConstruct` method is using a *producer method* in this way

```
@ApplicationScoped
class AuthManagerProducer {
  @Produces 
  @ApplicationScoped 
  AuthManager getAuthManager() { 
    return AuthManagerFactory.getAuthManager(new KeycloakFactoryAuth());
  }
}
```

and a more grained alternative:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class AuthManagerProducer {
  @Produces 
  @ApplicationScoped 
  AuthManager getAuthManager(KeycloakFactoryAuth keycloakFactoryAuth) { 
    return AuthManagerFactory.getAuthManager(keycloakFactoryAuth);
  }
  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  KeycloakFactoryAuth getKeycloakFactoryAuth() {
    return new KeycloakFactoryAuth();
  }
}
```

Feel free to inject configuration in `AuthManagerProducer` and customize `KeycloakFactoryAuth` as well as `AuthManager`